# Insert to Database on HTML Form Submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a form that allows a user to enter data. At the end, there is a submit button that can be pressed that submits the data entered, into a database. I had this working a few weeks ago but had to take a detour on a few other projects. I've come back to it now and the insertion doesn't seem to be working and I am not sure why.

So I am mainly focused on the bottom of the code with the SQL statements but have provided the other HTML for your reference. Do you see any problems that I may have in my SQL statements at all?

Also note that the page itself does not load if this section of sql code is not commented out:

```
INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Agreements 
(
    Terms, 
    Tier, 
    `Tier Minimum`, 
    Multiplier, 
    UOM, 
    Retro, 
    Guaranteed, 
    Pay
) 
VALUES 
(
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][term]]',
    '$_POST[tier]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][purchase_minimum]]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][multiplier]]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][uom]]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][retro]]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][guaranteed]]',
    '$_POST[rows[0][0][paid]]'
)
```

But if it is not commented out, the page does not load for some reason.

If we can somehow get this fixed, it would be much appreciated!

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxx";
    $dbName="xxxxxxxxx";
    $dbUser="xxxxxxx";
    $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);

    $usersQuery = "SELECT MR_Name, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P FROM Stage_Rebate_Master";

    $users = $dbh->query($usersQuery);

?>

<html>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <header>
          <h2>test</h2>
      </header>

    <div class="container">

<form name="form1" action="confirmation.php" method="POST">

<!-- Vendor -->

<section class="desc-block-left0" align="left">
<div>
<div id="vendor">
<strong>Vendor:</strong>
</div> 

<div class="align">
<select name="vendor_dropdown" id="ven" onChange="updateinput();">
    <option value="">Choose a Vendor</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user): ?>
            <option
                    data-name="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_N'];?>"
                    data-email="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_E'];?>"
                    data-phone="<?php echo $user['MR_POC_P'];?>"
            >
                <?php echo $user['MR_Name'];?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Program Name -->

<section class="desc-block-right0">
<div>
<div id="program_name">
<strong>Program Name:</strong><br>
</div>

<div class="align1">
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="program_name1" name="program_name" style="width: 50%">
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Program Period -->

<section class="desc-block-left1">
<div>
<div id="program_period">
<strong>Program Period:</strong>
</div>

<div class="align">
<input type="text" name="program_period_dropdown" id="period" value="<?php echo date("Y");?>" readonly style="width: 50px">
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Terms -->

<section class="desc-block-right1">
<div>
<div id="terms">
<strong>Terms:</strong><br>
</div>

<div class="align1">
<input type="text" id="year" name="term" style="width: 50px">
<label for="percent">%</label>
<input type="text" id="year" name="term" style="width: 50px">
<label for="percent">Net</label>
<input type="text" id="year" name="term" style="width: 50px">
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Vendor Type -->

<section class="desc-block-left2">
<div>
<div id="vendor_type">
<strong>Vendor Type:</strong><br>
</div>

<div class="align">
<table align="left">
    <tr align="center">
        <td><input type="radio" name="ven_type" value="Coded" id="type" checked="true"></td>
        <td align="left">Coded</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><input type="radio" name="ven_type" value="Non-Coded" id="type"></td>
        <td>Non-Coded</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Contact Information -->

<section class="desc-block-right2" align="center">
<div>
<div id="contact_info">
<strong>Contact Information:</strong><br>
</div>

<div class="align1">
<table align="left" id="contact">
<tr align="left">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" class="name" name="name"></td>
        <td><input type="email" id="email" class="email" name="email"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" id="tel" class="tel" name="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="save" name="edit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>
</section>

<!-- 400 Rebate Tables -->
<!-- 400P -->

<div align="center" id="border">
<div id="rebate_400p">
<strong>400P</strong><br>
</div>

<table id="tables" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="center" class="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="center" name="tier" id="tier">1</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="purchase_min" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[0][0][purchase_minimum]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="multiplier" data-name="multiplier" name="rows[0][0][multiplier]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id ="uom" data-name="uom" name="rows[0][0][uom]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="retro" data-name="retro"  name="rows[0][0][retro]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="guaranteed" data-name="guaranteed" name="rows[0][0][guaranteed]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="paid" data-name="paid" name="rows[0][0][paid]"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow()"></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<!-- 400M -->
<div id="rebate_400m">
<strong>400M</strong><br>
</div>

<table cellspacing="5" id="tables1" style="display: none;">
    <tr align="center" class="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Rows</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="center" name="tier" id="tier1">1</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="purchase_min1" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[1][0][purchase_minimum]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="multiplier1" data-name="multiplier" name="rows[1][0][multiplier]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id ="uom1" data-name="uom" name="rows[1][0][uom]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="retro1" data-name="retro"  name="rows[1][0][retro]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="guaranteed1" data-name="guaranteed" name="rows[1][0][guaranteed]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="paid1" data-name="paid" name="rows[1][0][paid]"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow1()"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<!-- Button to display table for 400M -->
<input type="button" name="row" value="+" onclick="show2();"/>

<!-- 400D -->

<div id="rebate_400d">
<strong>400D</strong><br>
</div>

<table cellspacing="5" id="tables2" style="display: none;">
    <tr align="center" class="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Rows</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="center" name="tier" id="tier2">1</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="purchase_min2" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[2][0][purchase_minimum]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="multiplier2" data-name="multiplier" name="rows[2][0][multiplier]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id ="uom2" data-name="uom" name="rows[2][0][uom]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="retro2" data-name="retro"  name="rows[2][0][retro]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="guaranteed2" data-name="guaranteed" name="rows[2][0][guaranteed]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="rebate_tables" id="paid2" data-name="paid" name="rows[2][0][paid]"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow2()"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<!-- Button to adisplay table for 400D -->
<input type="button" name="row" value="+" id="plus-button" onclick="show3();"/>
</div>

<!-- Products -->

<div id="align">
<p>
<div id="products">
<strong>Products:</strong><br>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="product" value="All" onclick="hide();"/ checked> All 
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Category" onclick="show();"/> Category 
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Sku" onclick="hide();"/> Sku
    <select multiple id="area" name="category" style="display: none;">
        <option value="Example A" align ="center">Example A</option>
        <option value="Example B" align ="center">Example B</option>
        <option value="Example C" align ="center">Example C</option>
        <option value="Example D" align ="center">Example D</option>
        <option value="Example E" align ="center">Example E</option>
        <option value="Example F" align ="center">Example F</option>
    </select>
</p>

<!-- Submit Button -->

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" name="submit">
</div>

</form>

    </div>

    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    <footer>
        <h3>test</h3>
    </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

  {

  $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_Name, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES ('$_POST[vendor_dropdown]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[number]')";

  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Programs (Program_Year) VALUES ('$_POST[program_period_dropdown]')";

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Agreements (Terms, Tier, `Tier Minimum`, Multiplier, UOM, Retro, Guaranteed, Pay) VALUES ('$_POST[rows[0][0][term]]','$_POST[tier]','$_POST[rows[0][0][purchase_minimum]]','$_POST[rows[0][0][multiplier]]','$_POST[rows[0][0][uom]]','$_POST[rows[0][0][retro]]','$_POST[rows[0][0][guaranteed]]','$_POST[rows[0][0][paid]]')";

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Programs (Program_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[program_name]')";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
  $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
  $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);

  $result = $stmt->execute();
  $result1 = $stmt1->execute();
  $result2 = $stmt2->execute();
  $result3 = $stmt3->execute();

  echo json_encode($result);
  echo json_encode($result1);
  echo json_encode($result2);
  echo json_encode($result3);


}

?>
```

Comment: I re-tagged your question as `MySQL` instead of `SQL Server` due to the syntax used.

Comment: You're pretty open to SQL-Injection...

Comment: You need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yeah, this is something that would be for internal use...I will get to work on that, but want to fix this first

Comment: You need to check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php your question has too much for us to go over and debug.

Comment: If you don't write your page with parameterized queries from the beginning it will never happen. And don't assume that just because it is internal today that it doesn't matter. Your code may be used as an example by someone else or this site may be made external at some point. It is so easy to protect your system, just do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- theres not too much to the code, it looks like a lot but really its only the bottom PHP portion that needs looked at.....the rest is provided so you can see why I used the names that I used with `$_POST`

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: I see no errors shown when it is run

Comment: it submits a form and goes to another page so im not sure how i would be able to see anything in the console either

Comment: try to echo the values in the bottom PHP code.Check whether its getting displayed

Comment: Nothing is being displayed when I echo them...however, if i echo values from the top PHP portion, i can see values.

Comment: echo some string like  echo "test" to check whether that piece of code is running while clicking submit button

Comment: Actually it wasnt displaying because the code is in an `isset`....i removed that and it does echo the correct code, so it knows its there, just not working for some reason

Comment: The insert works because when `isset` is deleted, it inserts a new row in the table each time

Answer (score 0):

remove the `action=confirmation.php` attribute in `form`  ,as a result of which the bottom submit code is not working

```
<form name="form1" method="POST">
```

Thats enough

Comment: the insert works now....so now i just need to get to the confirmation page after submit is clicked

Comment: I still need to be able to get to the confirmation.php page after the submit is clicked

Comment: Then why not give this insert query also in confirmation page... or redirect to confirmation.php after the insert query

Comment: how would I do the redirect...that sounds like the better option...what ive seen online so far isnt working

Comment: header('Location: confirmation.php');

Comment: That's what I though, but am having no luck

Comment: then try giving it in <script> using `Window.location`

Comment: I used that and it worked, however, the confirmation page is suppose to display the information to the user that they entered as a confirmation....and this redirect does not bring in any information at all from the previous window since its not an action on the form any longer

Comment: then better you give insert query in confirmation.php page or you'll have to save the information for confirmation in session

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that...never done that before

Comment: then give insert query in confirmation page

Comment: So do I need to move my bottom portion of PHP to the beginning of my confirmation.php page??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135097/discussion-between-affaz-and-rataiczak24).